# cakephp/apache create multiple session for same user

Tags: php, apache, session, cakephp

I work on a cakephp 2 website this month so  i beggin with this. 
the website is in production since 3 years and working.

The problem is that sometimes apache create a new session for a user who already have a session while browsing the website. So the user have to loggin again and loose his actual work.
I deploy the website with xampp on windows and i have the same problem.

In the `xampp\tmp` folder i see new files creating but i'm alone on my localhost and i stop browsing only few secondes.

for example two sessions files created in the same minute

```
Config | a: 3: {
    s: 9: "userAgent";
    s: 32: "b6940efc452d3a691e416c43f2d1efa8";
    s: 4: "time";
    i: 1489043181;
    s: 9: "countdown";
    i: 10;
}
Message | a: 0: {}
```

-

```
Config | a: 3: {
    s: 9: "userAgent";
    s: 32: "b6940efc452d3a691e416c43f2d1efa8";
    s: 4: "time";
    i: 1489043188;
    s: 9: "countdown";
    i: 5;
}
Message | a: 0: {}
```

so the b6940efc452d3a691e416c43f2d1efa8 is the same in both files.

This is my cakephp config :

cakephp/app/config/core.php

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);

Configure::write('Error', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError',
    'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED,
    'trace' => true
));

Configure::write('Exception', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
    'renderer' => 'ExceptionRenderer',
    'log' => true
));

Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');


Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);
//Configure::write('Cache.check', true);

define('LOG_ERROR', 2);


Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake',
    'Session.cookie' => 'CAKEPHP',
    'Session.cookieTimeout'=>30,
    'Session.checkAgent' => false       
));
Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium');



Cache::config('_cake_core_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_core_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'persistent' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration
));

Cache::config('_cake_model_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_model_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'models' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration
));
```

cakephp/app/config/boostrap.php (i'm in dev mode)

```
Configure::write('debug', '2'); 
Configure::write(
        'Session', array('defaults' => 'php', 'timeout' => '900', 'autoRegenerate' => true)
);
Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);
```

And xampp php.ini

```
session.save_handler = files
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 0
session.save_handler = files
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 0
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
```

Any advice are welcomed
thanks

Comment: Whats set in php.ini for session.gc_maxlifetime?

Comment: Also - the `autoRegenerate` true flag will automatically regenerate the session key every n requests, https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#session-configuration I don't believe under normal circumstances this is supposed to trigger the need for login

Comment: Thanks for help. i have session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440 in local. I change bootstrap.php to Configure::write( 'Session', array('defaults' => 'php', 'timeout' => '3600', 'autoRegenerate' => false) ); i hope this resolve the new session issue